# Can't add outlets to an existing outlet collection in a normal way

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iboutlet, iboutletcollection

I'm using Xcode 6.3.2 with Objective-C.
I hook some label to my header file, and I choose outlet collection. Then, I try to hook another label to the same collection, and it's disabled in any way. I'm try to hook them from both sides, and nothing. There's a workaround I've figured out, which is also mentioned here:
[Wiring up Outlet Collection Trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25096955/wiring-up-outlet-collection-trouble)
The next label I hook, I manually write the same name of the previous outlet collection, then, obviously it creates a new line with the same names, it's a duplicate error, I delete this line, and the labels are hooked in the same collection. It's a workaround, and I don't like it too much. Any ideas of a proper solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears there is some bug when updating Xcode I guess. I've found out, that actually I can't connect any type of outlets, and I searched for an answer about this, and here's what I've found:
[xcode-6-cant-connect-any-iboutlet-to-viewcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26203970/xcode-6-cant-connect-any-iboutlet-to-viewcontroller)

This did solve my problem, but still, it's a major workaround. If anyone knows about a proper solution to this issue, I'd like to hear about that.