# Array of Outlets of type Label

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, iboutlet, iboutletcollection

I have 16 Outlets variables.

```
@IBOutlet var label00: UILabel?
@IBOutlet var label01: UILabel?
@IBOutlet var label02: UILabel?
@IBOutlet var label03: UILabel?
@IBOutlet var label10: UILabel?
@IBOutlet var label11: UILabel?
@IBOutlet var label12: UILabel?
@IBOutlet var label13: UILabel?
@IBOutlet var label20: UILabel?
@IBOutlet var label21: UILabel?
@IBOutlet var label22: UILabel?
@IBOutlet var label23: UILabel?
@IBOutlet var label30: UILabel?
@IBOutlet var label31: UILabel?
@IBOutlet var label32: UILabel?
@IBOutlet var label33: UILabel?
```

I want to declare them as an array but don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to create `IBOutlet` Collection like as

```
@IBOutlet var labels: Array<UILabel>!
```

For more reference of code check this question :

1) [Can't hook up an outlet collection in Xcode 6 using storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066270/cant-hook-up-an-outlet-collection-in-xcode-6-using-storyboard)

2) [Swift - IBOutletCollection equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24052459/swift-iboutletcollection-equivalent)

For example :

[image]

Comment: and How to set their limits

Comment: this will also help what you are saying but i want to set the limits to avoids the errors and exceptions. so can I set limit or not

Comment: and i want to make array of type 4*4. so how to declare that

Comment: @hatim please check the updated code. if you are going for multidimensional then you have to declare array as multidimensional.

Comment: @hatim Welcome anytime :)

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to create an array of outlets an connect it with IB Elements:

- Create an array of IBOutlets
- Add multiple UIElements (Views) in your Storyboard ViewController interface
- Select ViewController (In storyboard) and open connection inspector
- There is option 'Outlet Collections' in connection inspector (You will see an array of outlets there)
- Connect if with your interface elements

-

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet var collection:[UIView]!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

[image]