# Hide many labels with a counter variable

Tags: swift, variables

I have 11 Labels and a variable that counts from 1 to 11. If it counts to 5, for example, I want the first 5 Labels to be not hidden and the Labels 6-11 to be hidden. But now I have 11 big if statement and this is not good. But I don't know how to do this. Sadly, I couldn't find answers to my question.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure your labels are in an array. This includes using an outlet collection. See [Swift put multiple IBOutlets in an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24805180/swift-put-multiple-iboutlets-in-an-array) for more on that if you don't know how to do it.

Let's say you have your array of labels:

```
@IBOutlet var labels: [UILabel]!
```

Now you can create a function that takes a count and updates all of the labels:

```
func updateLabels(_ count: Int) {
    for index in 0..<labels.count {
        labels[index].isHidden = index >= count
    }
}
```