# Objective C: Is there the way to enumerate properties in code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties

I have Objective C class with properties:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelText1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelText2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelText3;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelText4;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelText5;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelText6;
```

Is there the way to enumerate it in code?
Something like:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
{
    theCell.labelText i.text = @"some value";
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: For the specific example above, I would just use a outlet collection instead of outlets for individual UILabels.  Then you could iterate over all the labels through the outlet collection which would be an array of UILabels

Answer (score 1):

You can use KVC to access those properties.

```
  NSArray *allProperties = @[@"labelText1", @"labelText2", @"labelText3", @"labelText4", @"labelText5", @"labelText6"];

for (NSString *aProperty in allProperties) {
   UILabel *label = [theCell valueForKey:aProperty];
   label.text = @"some value";
}
```

This would yield you the result you want. Anyway, I would suggest you to create IBOutletCollection for such UI element or an array of only those that you want to iterate through.

Comment: In case anyone is using Swift, IBOutletCollection is not supported in Swift.

Comment: @user965972 Have you seen the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24052459/swift-iboutletcollection-equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an IBOutletCollection of UILabel properties:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *myControllerLabels;
```

In your storyboard or .xib file, control-drag from the UILabel elements to this property.

Then in your code you can perform the following:

```
    [self.myControllerLabels enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UILabel *label, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    label.text = @"some value";
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but I wouldn't recommend using it in a real application. The objective-C runtime is pretty open: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/index.html

There are a number of methods that will give you the properties.

Comment: Thanks! I am quite newbie in objective-C. Could you explain why it's a bad idea? I am curious about it, cause I had written the code but I came up with idea that it will look better with automatically enumeration of different situations...

Comment: The above suggestions are much better in real applications. Using the runtime might leave you open to a future version (unlikely now since Swift is the future) where they are no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `@selector()` by calling `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` on `theCell` and passing in the `NSString` as the object.

```
NSString *selectorName;
for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
{
    selectorName = [NSString stringWithFormat:"setLabelText%i", i];
    [theCell performSelector:@selector(selectorName) withObject:@"some value"];
}
```