# How to change property for multiple IBOutlet

Tags: ios, swift

For example If I have multiple IBOutlet like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var x1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var x2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var x3: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var x4: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var x5: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var x6: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var x7: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var x8: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var x9: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var x10: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var x11: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var x12: UITextField!
```

How to change for example the border for all the IBOutlet :

```
self.x1.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
self.x1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
self.x1.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
```

without writing a lot of code?

Comment: Hint: use an IBOutletcollection or enumerate through the subviews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a collection of `IBOutlet`s in Swift, like this:

```
@IBOutlet var collectionOfTextFields: Array<UITextField>?
```

Use IB to add all the desired fields to `collectionOfTextFields`. Now you can use a simple loop to set attributes of all your text fields without writing a lot of code.

You should be able to go even further, and eliminate all your `x1`..`x12` variables from the code by setting `tag` attribute of your `UITextField`s in IB, and them using these tags in your processing code to differentiate among the twelve fields in your interface.

Comment: How to find an IBOutlet from the array?

Comment: @Sarita Iterate and look for the tag that you gave it in the interface builder. [Here is an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24066595/335858) that shows how to enumerate a collection of UI elements.

Answer (score 0):

Add them to an array and loop through it.

```
for var x: UITextField in array {
  x.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
  ...
}
```