# How to apply same function to all the textfields in the controller without specifying each one

Tags: ios, swift

hello I want to know how can I generically define function which can be apply to all of the `UITextFields` in specific `UIViewController` on which I am working in. Lets say If I have 10 textfields and I want all of them to be hidden, or seteditable false or true. I don't want to write like this textfield

```
textField1.hidden = true
textField2.hidden = true
textField3.hidden = true
etc etc
```

Hope you understand my question

Comment: You can keep them in a `UIView' or `UIScrollView' then you just have to hide and show the `superview` of all textfields. Another way to create a `IBOutletCollection` .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24052459/swift-iboutletcollection-equivalent

Comment: I would subclass UIViewController and I would add a method setTextFieldsHidden:(bool)isHidden. Then inside the controller I would just iterate through the subView and check if it is a class of UITextField or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var hidden = true { didSet { view.subviews.forEach { ($0 as? UITextField)?.hidden = hidden } } }
```

This will hide / unhide all your textfields when you change the value of `hidden`

Answer (score 1):

You can recursively find all UITextField instances in your view with a function like this. Pass your highest level view that contains the UITextFields or the views that contain your UITextFields (since this is recursive) as the view parameter;

```
func getTextFieldsInView(view: UIView) -> [UITextField] {
    var arrayTextFields = [UITextField]()

    for subview in view.subviews {
        arrayTextFields += getTextFieldsInView(subview)

        if let subview = subview as? UITextField {
            arrayTextFields.append(subview)
            //you can also do what you want here like: subview.hidden = true
        }
    }
    return arrayTextFields
}
```

This way you don't have to add them one by one to an array. Just assign the function call to a variable and the array is created dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep an array of all textfields and then forEach through the collection.

```
let textFields = [textField1, textField2, textField3, textField4]
textFields.forEach { $0.hidden = true }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your text fields are in Interface Builder you could create an IBOutletCollection for them and perform operations on them as a group

```
// Swift
@IBOutlet var semiBoldLabels: [UITextField]!

// ObjC
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutletCollection(UITextField) NSArray *textFields;
```