# Add border to all labels in a view

Tags: ios, swift

In my app I have a custom view `containerView` in this view there are more than 20 labels and I want to apply a border style to all of them.

Is there a way to avoid to add the border to each of them avoiding to have a long list?

Something similar to:

```
for each label in containerView {

   labels.layer.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor.CGColor

}
```

Comment: I'd make custom label `BorderedLabel` with border and make those labels to be of this type.

Comment: thanks found an easier way using `for loop`

Comment: Where did you get Swift 3 ? ;-)

Comment: IBOutletCollection might be an idea if you are using interface builder

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24066595/669586

Comment: i do not agree that the for loop is the easier (and more elegant) way than creating a subclass. :) but that is just my personal opinion... if you want to use those labels in different viewcontrollers you have to create a for loop for each viewcontroller for example...

Comment: @AndréSlotta Actually, there is no need for it either, you can just set the `layer ` properties directly in Interface builder.

Comment: @Sulthan sure you can but you have to set it for EACH label. that is not really elegant and maintainable. lets say you want to change the border's width you have to do it for EACH label.

Comment: @AndréSlotta True, thanks god we have `@IBDesignable` now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `borderWidth`.

```
for subview in self.view.containerView.subviews as! [UIView] {

    if let label = subview as? UILabel {
       label.layer.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
       label.layer.borderWidth = 1
    }

}
```

**Swift 4**

```
label.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
```

Comment: just for reference, the latest version of swift changes that color line to `UIColor.green.cgColor`

Answer (score 2):

create a subclass like this:

```
@IBDesignable
class BorderedLabel: UILabel {

    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            layer.borderColor = borderColor?.CGColor
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }

}
```

then change your label's custom class in interface builder, set the borderColor / borderWidth properties you like and see the results live in interface builder!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
for view in self.view.containerView.subviews as! [UIView] {
    if let label = view as? UITextField {
           label.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor;
           label.layer.borderWidth = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Even better then my solution as it won't crash if there are no image views. However, I found that all the image views are wrapped in a secondary view called 'imageContainerView'

Comment: However, the code says : Forced cast of '[UIView]' to same type has no effect

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

```
for imageViews in self.containerView.subviews as! [UIImageView] {

            imageViews.layer.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
            imageViews.layer.borderWidth = 1

        }
```